# Vectorized implementation of finding a given set of point within a given set of polygons

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, geospatial, geopandas

I have over 1M latitude, longitude points and I am trying to find it exists in a given set of polygons. I am trying to implement Vectored implementation for this case

I tried using geopandas for faster approach but it also did not solve the problem.Can you help me on how to go about this.

```
point1 = Point(-74.470186, 43.052175)
point2 = Point(-74.470238, 43.052186)
point3 = Point(-74.470299, 43.052019)

poly1 = polygon([[-74.470186, 43.052175], [-74.470238, 43.052186], [-74.470299, 43.052019], [-74.470246, 43.052009], [-74.470186, 43.052175]])
poly2 = polygon([[-74.470186, 43.052175], [-74.470238, 43.052186], [-74.470299, 43.052019], [-74.470246, 43.052009], [-74.470186, 43.052175]])


                                            geometry
0  POLYGON ((-74.47019 43.05217, -74.47024 43.052...
1  POLYGON ((-74.50768 43.02109, -74.50755 43.021...
2  POLYGON ((-74.41400 43.05330, -74.41391 43.053...
3  POLYGON ((-74.35576 43.05724, -74.35573 43.057...
4  POLYGON ((-74.38048 43.04536, -74.38035 43.045...


import time
import shapely.speedups
shapely.speedups.enable()
start_time = time.time()
print(geo_df_ny.geometry.within(point))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))


0          False
1          False
2          False
3          False
4          False
           ...  
4844433    False
4844434    False
4844435    False
4844436    False
4844437    False
Length: 4844438, dtype: bool
--- 15.30899977684021 seconds ---
```

The above code does not help as it takes over 15 seconds for one point. I have over million points. I need someone to help me implement vectored one.

Comment: You need to do a spatial join. Check out [`geopandas.sjoin`](http://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html).

Comment: i am not looking to join. i need to find if a point exists within a polygon or not

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you want to check if a point is inside of a polygon?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is i have over a million points and million polygons

Comment: I don't think vectorized execution would help much. You need indices, either by creating sindex explicitly, or using sjoin (use left join, if polygon is Nullafter join, you have no match, otherwise you have a match).

Comment: @SudharsanaRajasekaran That's *exactly* what a spatial join is.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was able to successfully implement the logic I need using spatial join.